# How do I add a tap gesture to an image with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is quite basic, I'm starting out with swift and I couldn't find a working example.

I'd like to tap an image and do an action. The IBOutlet is linked to an image on the Main Storyboard. When I tap it, I get nothing. I was expecting to get a console message. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tapView: UIImageView!
    let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        tapRec.addTarget(self, action: "tappedView")
        tapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)

    }

    func tappedView(){
        println("image tapped")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe you need to enable user interaction on a UIImageView. Its set to false by default. Try:

```
tapView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks! (Note: variable should be tapView.)